# javascript IE issue . Not working in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Branching Drop down Effect (not Sure about the Name) . I am not Good in javascript and jquery but I can modify little .And with that knowledge I made this Effect .

You can See the Live Demo : http://saifraihan.webege.com/Branching%20New/branching.html

Here is my:

**HTML**

```
<form id="survey" action="#" method="post">
    <div id="section">
            <label for="Select">Select a step</label>
            <select id="select" onchange="selection(this);">
                    <option value="none">
                            Input1
                    </option>
                    <option value="radio">
                            Radio1
                    </option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" style="display:none;">
            <input name="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="section5" style="display:none;">
            <p>
                    Radio Step 1<br/>
                    <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="radio" id="RadioGroup2_0">
                            Radio</label>
                    <br>
                    <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="radio" id="RadioGroup2_1">
                            Radio</label>
                    <br>
            </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var sections ={
'none': 'section2',
'radio': 'section5'



};

var selection = function(select) {

 for(i in sections)
    document.getElementById(sections[i]).style.display = "none";    
    document.getElementById(sections[select.value]).style.display = "block";

}
```

This Example Working Great in FF , Chrome and Opera . BUT the **PROBLEM** is , it's not working in any version of IE . I am not sure why . As I am weak in javascripts I am not figuring out why this is not running in IE . Can there be any solution of this ? If can IT will be great .

Thanks In advance .

Answer (score 1):

Bind your event like this:

```
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function() { selection(this) });
```

That seemed to fix things for me in IE (10).  If you need to support 8 or before: events are attached using `attchEvent` in these versions of IE. So you'll need to write that logic as well (or you can use jQuery or some other library to handle the crossbrowser stuff for you).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnuFq/2/

Comment: this is great and working upto IE 9 . thank you very much . Also what jQuery I can use there to support IE 8 and later ? can You help me about this ? Sorry I am just very poor in knowledge of this jQuery and javascripts

Comment: You use the same jQuery for everything. That's the whole point of it. It's a normalization tool for the DOM API.

Comment: In jQuery you'd do `$('#select').on('change', function(e) { //... });`